# Luarocks: How do you install a rock from specific a account

Tags: lua, luarocks

How do you install a rock from a specific account? For example, I've forked a repository, made some changes and uploaded my own version of that code to my luarocks account. How do I install my version instead of the global version?

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to your account's version of the rock, it will show you a command you can use to install the rock:

```
$ luarocks install --server=http://luarocks.org/manifests/<your_username> <rock_name>
```